# Create unit-testing service with promise in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service return promise needd unit-test.

```
var urlQuestions = "user/securityQuestions";
   AccountService.getServerDataForUrl(urlQuestions)
   .then(function (data) {
         $scope.securityQuestions = data;
   }, function (error) {
});
```

And this is my unit-test:

```
it('submit should call the AccountService.getServerDataForUrl', function () {
        var urlQuestions = "user/securityQuestions"; 
        var error;
        var deferredSuccess = $q.defer();
        spyOn(AccountService, 'getServerDataForUrl').and.returnValue(deferredSuccess.promise);

        expect(AccountService.getServerDataForUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith(urlQuestions);

        deferredSuccess.resolve(); 
        $scope.$digest();

        expect(error).toBe(null);
        expect($scope.securityQuestions).toEqual(data);
});
```

But when I run it, it make some error:

> Expected spy getServerDataForUrl to have been called with [
>   'user/securityQuestions' ]

but it was never called.

> Error: Unexpected request: GET user/securityQuestions No more request expected

Comment: Could you post the complete code please. You are testing a controller not the service right?

Comment: @MattHerbstritt: Yes, I want to create unit-testing for my controller. My controller source code is too long, but I only want to test this code. :)

Comment: I was mainly talking about the rest of your spec. Need to see where/how you are creating your controller. It would be best if you could create a plunker demonstrating the issue and post the link.

Comment: Where do you call `AccountService.getServerDataForUrl` in unit-test?

Comment: @KirillSlatin: This all code in my unit-test except describe and beforeEach

Comment: Then there is nothing in this unit-test that makes it actually a test. A unit-test is supposed to test (without modifying it) some functionality by calling it and verifying results.